# Why does this example of inheritance not work on my computer?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

I have some Java background but now I am trying to write some simple games in JavaScript and HTML. I'm struggling to understand how OOP works because it seems like there are different ways of creating objects? I wrote this snippet referencing a friend's code but the console gives me "uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'roar' of undefined". Why does the code work for him but not for me? Is he running some kind of server side library?

**test.js:**

```
function Animal() {

    this.needsAir = true;

    this.roar = function() {

        console.log("roar");    

    }

}

function Bear() {

    Animal.call();

}

var init = function() {

    var bear = new Bear();
    bear.roar();
    console.log(bear.needsAir)

}
```

**index.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function() {
                    init();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, the `this` of Bear and `this` of Animal are two different objects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to `.call`.

```
function Bear() {

    Animal.call(this);

}
```

Also, your prototype inheritance isn't complete as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions have different `this` -- try to use the `apply` methods, which would get you somewhat further, like;

```
function Bear() {
    Animal.apply(this);
}
```

There are a lot more in javascript which is needed, such as prototype definitions

Answer (score 0):

your Bear function needs to pass `this` to Animal call.

To understand javascript inheritance better you can check out this [blog on understanding javascript inheritance](https://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/04/understanding-javascript-inheritance/)

Comment: Thank you, your link is helpful.